# Emprical argument in mvrnorm function from the R package 'MASS'

Tags: simulation

I'm just wondering what is the difference between empirical = TRUE or FALSE when simulating normally distributed multivariate. Is it that when empirical = TRUE every simulated data will indicate the identical preset covariance matrix?

Comment: You could generate a tiny dataset and check in less time that you will have to wait for an answer...

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for your suggestion! I just forgot this very simple option ... I tried both argument settings. When empirical = TRUE, the generated dataset will exactly replicate the specified covariance matrix. When empirical = FALSE, the generated dataset would contain more or less sampling error as noted by Billy. But many thanks for all of the answers!

Answer (score -1):

"If true, mu and Sigma specify the empirical not population mean and covariance matrix." (from mvrnorm documentation)

Meaning that if TRUE, the covariance matrix would be as specified

Comment: A covariance must always be specified (this is the `Sigma` argument). The documentation just specifies that when `empirical = TRUE` then the provided mean and covariance matrix are sample-based estimates (i.e., derived empirically) whereas when `empirical = FALSE` the mean and covariance matrix are treated as known/true population parameters estimated without sampling error

Comment: Would you want to make that an answer and I can delete mine copied from the documentation?

Comment: These answers are all valuable! I would rather retain all of them for those who may have similar questions. Many thanks to both of you!