# meaning of empirical argument in mvrnorm

Tags: r, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm using the `mvrnorm` function from `MASS` library, and I have a question regarding the `empirical` argument.

In one of the comments in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577513/emprical-argument-in-mvrnorm-function-from-the-r-package-mass), Billy says "`when empirical = FALSE the mean and covariance matrix are treated as known/true population parameters estimated without sampling error`", whereas Bo WANG in his comment interprets this as meaning "`When empirical = FALSE, the generated dataset would contain more or less sampling error as noted by Billy.`"

Are these two comments really equivalent?

When I run this function, the covariance and sample means are indeed always different, so there is sampling error. But maybe I misunderstood Billy's comment?

Comment: This is hard to answer because you haven't expressed any specific understanding or interpretation of Billy's comment.  There is no contradiction between the statements, though.  Perhaps the principal difficulty is the *non sequitur* of Billy's comment.  It is immaterial how the parameters were determined: the algorithm neither knows nor cares.

Comment: The way I read Billy's comment was that when `empirical` is set to False, then the simulated dataset would not contain sampling error, whereas I understood Bo Wang's comment as saying the simulated dataset will contain sampling error. But I think I'm misunderstanding the `without sampling error` in Billy's comment...